# MS access Convert Value Range to Separate row

Tags: ms-access

How do I convert below from and To value range into single rows as shown in To in MS Access ? Value from and To could be either Numberic OR Non Numeric for from and To field as shown below. Some values does not have To.

```
From:
Role    Field  From     To
Role1   F1      9411    9413
Role2   F2      9410    9412
Role1   F1      9999
Role1   F3      ABCD
Role2   F3      ABCD    ZZZZ

To:
Role    Field  From     To
Role1   F1      9411    
Role1   F1      9412    
Role1   F1      9413    
Role2   F2      9410    
Role2   F2      9411
Role2   F2      9412
Role1   F1      9999
Role1   F3      ABCD
Role2   F3      ABCD    ZZZZ
```

Comment: Serious? The last could represent about 1/3 mio. records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to loop the records in the first table, and then have an "inner" loop that goes between the two values to add data to the second table. Something like:

```
Sub sAddData()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSteer As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngFrom As Long
    Dim lngTo As Long
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblTo;"
    Set rsSteer = db.OpenRecordset("tblFrom")
    If Not (rsSteer.BOF And rsSteer.EOF) Then
        Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("tblTo")
        Do
            If (IsNumeric(rsSteer("From"))) And (IsNumeric(rsSteer("To"))) Then
                lngFrom = CLng(rsSteer("From"))
                lngTo = CLng(rsSteer("To"))
                For lngLoop1 = lngFrom To lngTo
                    rsData.AddNew
                    rsData("Role") = rsSteer("Role")
                    rsData("Field") = rsSteer("Field")
                    rsData("Value") = lngLoop1
                    rsData.Update
                Next lngLoop1
            ElseIf IsNumeric(rsSteer("From")) Then
                rsData.AddNew
                rsData("Role") = rsSteer("Role")
                rsData("Field") = rsSteer("Field")
                rsData("Value") = CLng(rsSteer("From"))
                rsData.Update
            End If
            rsSteer.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsSteer.EOF
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsSteer.Close
    rsData.Close
    Set rsSteer = Nothing
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sAddData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Code has been modified to deal with the possibility that either of the fields "From" or "To" may be Non-Numeric.

Regards,

Comment: Thank You. I am getting Type Mismatch error at or lngLoop1 = rsSteer("From") To rsSteer("To") since some of the TO Fields are blank.

Comment: I've changed the code to use `Nz` (Null to Zero) to deal with null values in `rsSteer("To")`.

Comment: For lngLoop1 = rsSteer("From") To Nz(rsSteer("To"), rsSteer("From")) is giving me type mismatch when Nz(rsSteer("To") is Blank. From and To fields are short text since it does have non number values as well which should remain same

Comment: Is there any possibility that "From" could be Numeric and "To" Non-Numeric? And what happens if both "From" and "To" are Non-Numeric?

Comment: If it is Numeric then it will be for both(From and To), Keep the same from and to value for Non Numeric.

Comment: Updated sample data

Comment: What field does "ZZZZ" go into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query.

First, create a small query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM MSysObjects;
```

Save it as **Ten**, and then create the final query:

```sql
SELECT 
    RoleNumbers.Role, 
    RoleNumbers.Field, 
    [From] + [N] AS [Value]
FROM 
    RoleNumbers, 
    Ten
WHERE 
    [From] + [N] <= [To]
ORDER BY 
    RoleNumbers.Role, 
    [From] + [N];
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very creative indeed. I forgot to mention, I have other values part of the same table does not have range, some are Text values causing type Mismatch error in final query

Comment: Well, we only have your sample data, and there is no default method to "count" text values.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated sample data. I must say, Your solution is very creative.